# how to aggregate decimal with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I try to

```
Collection.Aggregate(0.0,(current, next) => current += next.decimalValue);
```

but I get error of casting decimal to double

another issue: For "Sum" Linq the seed is the default type value?
meaning seed = 0 for decimal...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler interprets `0.0` as a double, you need to specify the type as a decimal. Try the following:

```
Collection.Aggregate(0m, (current, next) => current += next.decimalValue);
```

[The `m` suffix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) indicates that the numeric real literal (in this case `0`) is a decimal.

Comment: For "Sum" Linq the seed is the default type value? meaning seed = 0 for decimal...

Comment: I'm not sure what's the implications of it, but you can use the operator `+` instead of  `+=`.

Comment: @Jp_ there would be no functional change, but would remove an unnecessary assignment (and make the code clearer since current is not passed by ref)... Having `+` instead of `+=` would be an improvement!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `0.0M`:

```
Collection.Aggregate(0.0M,(current, next) => current += next.decimalValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

`0.0` is a double you have to explicitly create a decimal:

```
Collection.Aggregate(new decimal(0.0), (current, next) => current += next.decimalValue);
```

Comment: This syntax is declaring a `double` -- `0.0` -- and then converting that double into a `decimal`. Why not just declare the `decimal` directly using the `m` suffix? (I suspect that you would run the risk of conversion/rounding errors etc with passing some non-zero `double` values into the `decimal` constructor.)

Comment: you should use a decimal literal (`0.0m`) rather than new up a decimal that receives a double literal

Comment: Yeah I gathered that from the two other answer. Truth is I didn't know it was possible, I looked into it some time back but wasn't able to find a way to do it for decimal. I obviously didn't make enough effort to find the answer back then. But I got it now for free :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 0.0m, 0m works to declare a decimal. Below is a snippet of working code.

```
     var itemSums = pCurrentList.Aggregate((TotalSealedUnits: 0m, TotalSealedUnitSqFt : 0m, TotalLinInches: 0m, TotalOrders: 0m  ), 
        (Results, current) => (Results.TotalSealedUnits += current.TotalSealedUnits, Results.TotalSealedUnitSqFt += current.TotalSUSqFt, Results.TotalLinInches += current.TotalLInches, Results.TotalOrders += 1));


    txtTotalOrders.Text = itemSums.TotalOrders.ToString();
    txtTotalLinInches.Text = itemSums.TotalLinInches.ToString();
    txttotalSU.Text = itemSums.TotalSealedUnits.ToString();
    txtTotalSUSqFt.Text = itemSums.TotalSealedUnitSqFt.ToString();
```